# Can I check if a script is running inside a Compute Engine or in a local environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I just wanted to know if there is a way to check whether a Python script is running inside a Compute Engine or in a local environment?

I want to check that in order to know how to authenticate, for example when a script runs on a Compute Engine and I want to initiate a BigQuery client I do not need to authenticate but when it comes to running a script locally I need to authenticate using a service account JSON file.

If I knew whether a script is running locally or in a Compute Engine I would be able to initiate Google services accordingly.

I could put initialization into a try-except statement but maybe there is another way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer by @DazWilkin is correct based upon your goal. You can determine if you are running on a Google compute service (GCE, Functions, Run, etc) by attempting to connect to the metadata server. I set a short connection timeout. More advanced methods include detecting the cloud vendor that your code is running on. If this file exists **/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json** you are most likely running in the cloud. The file has details that you can parse to confirm such as "cloud-name": "gce".

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, I think a better solution is provided by Google called Application Default Credentials. See [Best practices to securely auth apps in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications) (*thanks @sethvargo*) and [Application Default Credentials](https://google.aip.dev/auth/4110)

Using this mechanism, authentication becomes consistent regardless of where you run your app (on- or off-GCP). See [finding credentials automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python)

When you run off-GCP, you set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to the Service Account. When you run on-GCP (and, to be clear, you are still authenticating, it's just transparent), you don't set the environment variable because the library obtains the e.g. Compute Engine instance's service account for you.

Answer (score 1):

A little hacky but works just fine:

```
def in_google_network():
    url = "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id"
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(
            urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"Metadata-Flavor": "Google"})
        ).read().decode()
        logging.info("Running inside of google network.")
        return True
    except Exception:
        logging.info("Running outside of google network.")
    return False
```

You can't reach this endpoint from any other place than GCP

Comment: To improve your example, add a connection timeout. The default is very long.

Answer (score 0):

So I read a bit on the Google Cloud authentication and came up with this solution:

```
import google.auth
from google.oauth2 import service_account

try:
    credentials, project = google.auth.default()
except:
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/path/to/service_account_json_file.json')

client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

What this does is it tries to retrieve the default Google Cloud credentials (in environments such as Compute Engine) and if it fails it tries to authenticate using a service account JSON file.

It might not be the best solution but it works and I hope it will help someone else too.

Comment: Although this will work most of the time, there are situations where this code will throw an exception twice. You can be running on a computer service and no credentials are available (scopes disabled). Your except will execute and then throw another exception (file not found).